# What is Your developer key in youtube-videos script?

Tags: api, youtube

I try to use this https://www.sitepoint.com/displaying-youtube-videos-php article to use youtube video in 
my laravel 5 app , but reading it I found next :

```
// .env

APP_DEBUG=true

app_name='Your app name (optional)'
client_id='Your client id'
client_secret='Your client secret'
api_key='Your developer key'
```

I suppose that client_id/client_secret parameters are this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTV6v.jpg
Is it so?

But I ma not sure what is last parameter ?

```
api_key='Your developer key'
```

Is it value I need to get somewhere in Google's Developer Console ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuHLskIdT84 video. It has instruction you asked.